# Find if an unique index exists in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a reason to drop a Unique constraint if it already exists, where I may be modifying a field that it references.

My basic attempt is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableY].[UQ_X]'),'IsUniqueCnst'))
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableY]
    DROP CONSTRAINT [UQ_X]
END
```

The `OBJECT_ID` call always returns null and the code proceeds to try to drop the constraint, whether `[UQ_X]` exists or not.

Comment: A constraint is a separate object than the table. I think you want `IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.UQ_X', 'UQ') IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT scalar)` will always return `true` anyway irrespective of what value the scalar has

Comment: The `EXISTS` will always return a true here too. An `EXISTS` returns true *if* a `SELECT` statement returns a row; your `SELECT` *will* always return a row. It doesn't matter if that row only contains the value `NULL`, `NULL` is still a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the clues from the comments, I have a working option.

The solution seems to be to look at the `sys.key_constraints` data

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1
            FROM sys.key_constraints k
            WHERE k.parent_object_id =OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableY]')
              AND k.[type] = 'UQ'
              AND k.[name] ='UQ_X')
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableY]
    DROP CONSTRAINT [UQ_X]      
END
```